# How to interpret and access tsvector?

Tags: postgresql, search, tsvector

> A data type `tsvector` is provided for storing preprocessed documents, along with a type tsquery for representing processed queries

But sometimes TSVECTOR  is an array of words, sometimes a bag of word-position, sometimes a complex vector with positions and weights... Can I access the individual parts of its data structure?  Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( tsv TSVECTOR );
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
  ('foo phrase'::TSVECTOR),
  ('second foo phrase'::TSVECTOR),
  ('third foo phrase'::TSVECTOR);

SELECT tsv FROM t WHERE "'foo' is the first word" -- how to do it??
```

Imagining that TSVECTOR has the same JSONb structure-access operators: we can access its structure by `WHERE tsv->'foo'->0=1`.

In the real life: I not see ([here in the search-guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html)) a *tsquery* or direct operator that do it. And I not see ([here in the General Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch.html)) a **complete TSVECTOR  documentation**, with a technical description of **its real and complete internal structure**.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot, that's not what it is built for.

You would have to write a PostgreSQL extension in C to access the internal structure of the data type. The cumbersome alternative is to parse the text representation.